# Python ThreadPoolExecutor shutdown behaviour varies with where it's called from

Tags: python, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I've run two variants of code that, to me, should run exactly identically - so I'm very surprised to see different output from each...

First up:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

def func(x):
    print(f"In func {x}")
    sleep(1)
    return True

foo = executor.map(func, range(0, 10))

for f in foo:
    print(f"blah {f}")
    if f:
        break

print("Shutting down")
executor.shutdown(wait=False)
print("Shut down")
```

this outputs the following - showing remaining futures being run to completion.  While that surprised me at first, I believe it's consistent with the docs (in the absence of `cancel_futures` being set to `True`), as per https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown "Regardless of the value of wait, the entire Python program will not exit until all pending futures are done executing."

```
In func 0
In func 1
In func 2
In func 3
blah True
Shutting down
Shut down
In func 4
In func 5
In func 6
In func 7
In func 8
In func 9
```

So that's fine.  But here's the odd thing - if I refactor to call that within a function, it behaves differently.  See minor tweak:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

def run_test():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

    def func(x):
        print(f"In func {x}")
        sleep(1)
        return True

    foo = executor.map(func, range(0, 10))

    for f in foo:
        print(f"blah {f}")
        if f:
            break

    print("Shutting down")
    executor.shutdown(wait=False)
    print("Shut down")

run_test()
```

this outputs the following, suggesting the future *are* cancelled in this case

```
In func 0
In func 1
In func 2
blah True
Shutting down
In func 3
Shut down
```

So I guess something is happening as the executor falls out of scope at the end of `run_test()`?  But this seems to contradict the docs (which don't mention this), and surely the executor similarly falls out of scope at the end of the first script??

Seen at both Python 3.8 and 3.9.

I expected the same output in the two cases, but they mis-matched

Comment: Good question, that is surprising. I also don't see any documentation of anything like this. I don't think it really falls out of scope in the first version, because that's a module scope. For a more direct comparison, you could `del executor`.

Answer (score 1):

This surprised me too. This code also reproduces your behaviour

```python
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep


def run_test():
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

    def func(x):
        print(f"In func {x}")
        sleep(1)

    foo = executor.map(func, range(0, 10))

    # a
    x = next(foo)
    # b

    print("Shutting down")
    executor.shutdown(wait=False)
    print("Shut down")

run_test()
```

If you run it as-is, it will run for first couple of integers between 0 and 10 and then exit. If you comment out the line between `#a` and `#b` then it runs all 10.

The reason, as far as I can tell, is that if you loop over the generator object (`foo`) at all (or call `next()` on it) then the code ends up in [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c06f74f1d66290b22de3f6d6e1fe32dd3e0786e1/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L612) iterator function in the CPython concurrent.futures._base source code.

When the `run_test()` function exits and `foo` goes out of scope, then you end up in [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c06f74f1d66290b22de3f6d6e1fe32dd3e0786e1/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L622) `finally` block, which cancels all pending futures.

In your example without a function, I believe your guess is correct that it is related to the order in which objects go out of scope. You can see this by commenting / un-commenting the line between `# a` and `# b` below

```python
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

def func(x):
    print(f"In func {x}")
    sleep(1)
    return True

foo = executor.map(func, range(0, 10))

next(foo)

# a
# del foo
# b

print("Shutting down")
executor.shutdown(wait=False)
print("Shut down")
```